# Matlab How to easily loop round array

Tags: matlab, slice

Hi i'm looking for a way to take a slice of an array from the near the end to near the beginning. I know I could do this in two parts, then add them, but it seems like such a commonly desired operation I thought matlab probably already has it built in but I couldn't find any information in my search.
To clarify I would like to be able to say:

```
y = 1:10
y(-3:3) or y(8:3)
returns:
8 9 10 1 2 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't think there's a way to do this, though you can do it quite concisely by concatinating indices like: `y([end-3:end 1:3])` or `y([8:end 1:3])`

Comment: Brilliant, that was just what I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
y = 1:10;   
n = 3;   
y([end-n+1:end 1:n]);
```

This returns

```
ans =

     8     9    10     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 3):

there actually *is* a way to do it (without splitting it up in a concatenation of the negative and positive part of indices): use the modulo operator on your desired range:

```
>>  y = 1:10;
>>  y(mod([-3:3]-1,numel(y))+1)

ans =

     7     8     9    10     1     2     3
```

This result consists of 7 numbers (opposing your desired [8 9 10 1 2 3]), which is logical because -3:3 actually spans 7 numbers.

The number 0 would correspond to y(end) with this method, -1 would correspond to y(end-1), etc.